# Electrodynamics, trouble understanding electric displacement

Tags: electrostatics

I've come across a question involving a capacitor:

"In a cylindrical capacitor the radius is a = 5 mm and the outer conducter got the radius of b=25 mm. The isolation is 2 coaxial layers with the relative permittivity $e_{r1}=4 $ and $e_{r2}=2$ counting from the middle and out."

I'm supposed to calculate how thick the two layers should be to make sure that the electrical fields are equally strong.

According to my teacher, $D = k/s$ in the region $a < s < b$ but he is also mentioning this is because there are no free charges in that area, I cannot understand that because according to Gauss law, $D \cdot da = Q_{fenc}$.

($Q_{fenc}$ is the free charge).

What am I not understanding about this?

Comment: According to my teacher, D = k/s in the region a<s<b but he is also mentioning this is because there are no free charges in that area, I cannot understand that because according to Gauss law, D*da = Qfenc (Qfenc is the free charge). What am I not understanding about this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical problem. Your teacher is right, that's the correct form.

See that your problem has a cylindrical symmetry, so the vector $\vec{D}$ can only be radial, (meaning $\rho$-radial in cylindrical coordinates).

Now, you apply the Gauss law for the vector $D$, but in **differential form**, which is $div(D)=\rho_{free}$. If there are no free charges, you have $\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{D}=0$. Now take the divergence of $D$ in cylindrical coordinates (caution: use your coordinate system or you will fail here).

You can use only the radial term, due to symmetry. You have
$ div(\vec{D})=\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r D_r)=0 $

so (if $r\neq0$, and it is not)

$ \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r D_r)=0  \ \Rightarrow \ r\cdot D_r = const. \ \Rightarrow \ D_r=const/r$.

So there you have your $D=k/s$. Of course it is only valid in that region.

Proceed always like that: 
1) divergence of $D$ in all regions.
2) boundary conditions to eliminate constants (continuity of the normal $D$-component.
3)Calculate electric fields ($E=D/\varepsilon$). 4) Calculate potentials
5) Force continuity of the potential and find the rest of the information (constants).

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thats a lot of help, thanks a lot for taking time to answer,  been struggling with this for a while now!

Comment: If you dont mind me asking yet another question, what should I think of when I determine if I want to use div(D) or div(E), I suppose it's "riskier" to use div(E) since that means any rho, not only the free ones, do you have any trick?

Comment: Of course, you can ask anything. As you said, you hit the wall of the non-free $\rho$, that's why $D$ was defined. The "trick" is the one I told you before. It is actually the WAY of solving all problems consisting in "layers" of conductors and isolators. You start with $div(D)$, like in your question, and you get $D$. Then you can continue with the rest of stages, I hope they're clear. In sum, the only trick is "as soon as you see a onion-layers problems in electrostatics, follow those steps". I don't know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm slowly realizing how I should do it I think! Thanks for the great responses